# How to split word file with formatting retained

Tags: vba, c#-4.0, ms-word

I am trying to split a word file, I have seen numerous links for it , but formatting is not getting preserved. only the string inside the file is there in the new splitted files, but I want to have all the images , bullets , etc. to be there in the new splitted files.
I tried it using C# but , interop assembly has a limitation that it can't reserve formatting.
Also thinking of converting into zip and then extract from the xml files?

The things I tried are:
 http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/966-word-split-document-into-multiple-documents.html
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872374(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Are your images linked or embedded? Is the document based on a template other than Normal.dotm? Please be more precise as to what exactly you have tried. Show some code so we know how you try to achieve this.

Comment: Please try the following and, if it works, it can also be done using code. But first we need to know what works for you :-) This assumes the document uses Heading styles and that you want to split the document at a Heading style.

Comment: 1) Open the document in Word. 2) Switch to the OUTLINE view and click the "Show Document" button. 3) Select the text that should be split off into a new document - starting with a heading style. 4) Click "Create". 5) Double-click the little "page" symbol next to the Heading style at the beginning of the sub-document you just created. This should open that content in a NEW document. 6) File/Save As to save this as an independent document. When you're done testing, close the original document WITHOUT SAVING. Does this give you the result you need?

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Once more: Is the doc based on any other template than Normal.dotm? What does "not working" mean? What gets lost? What do you expect and what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

If everything else is worked out, you can use `Range.FormattedText` from range objecr for both source and target documents to preserve formatting.

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.formattedtext.aspx

It also lists code for C#

```
Range FormattedText { get; set; }
```

Comment: @mukul nagpal: Is this what you want?